# How do i avoid the route overlapping the markers in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I fetch a route via the directions api and show custom markers along the route.

Retrieving the route seems to take too long. So the markers are loaded first and then the route covers them.

Route overlapping markers

[image: 1]

Can someone please help me? i have already tried everything possible and can't get any further.

```
<!-- Draw route -->
                    
                    // an arbitrary start will always be the same
                            // only the end or destination will change
                            const start = [4.897778886724403,52.37883849502549];
                    
                    // create a function to make a directions request
                        async function getRoute(end) {
                          // make a directions request using walking profile
                          // an arbitrary start will always be the same
                          // only the end or destination will change
                          const query = await fetch(
                            `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/walking/4.897778886724403%2C52.37883849502549%3B4.894414857475621%2C52.37909027166908%3B4.890263602261191%2C52.380960108494776%3B4.88841534183245%2C52.380346416451644%3B4.887000553169984%2C52.379360260501386%3B4.881660943959587%2C52.37889069512848%3B4.882432603304723%2C52.37630661871849%3B4.884182427141932%2C52.37670114883948%3B4.884094736203572%2C52.37647953701696%3B4.88029173126333%2C52.37555780307868%3B4.881821774608976%2C52.374863696727296%3B4.883050226273702%2C52.374968494612055%3B4.882473647579834%2C52.37005329717058%3B4.883593567551898%2C52.368904488988235%3B4.884936683581029%2C52.37025638134896%3B4.888926469442392%2C52.36808645529354?alternatives=false&continue_straight=true&geometries=geojson&overview=simplified&steps=false&access_token=##`,
                            { method: 'GET' }
                          );
                          const json = await query.json();
                          const data = json.routes[0];
                          const route = data.geometry.coordinates;
                          const geojson = {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            properties: {},
                            geometry: {
                              type: 'LineString',
                              coordinates: route
                            }
                          };
                          // if the route already exists on the map, we'll reset it using setData
                          if (map.getSource('route')) {
                            map.getSource('route').setData(geojson);
                          }
                          // otherwise, we'll make a new request
                          else {
                            map.addLayer({
                              id: 'route',
                              type: 'line',
                              source: {
                                type: 'geojson',
                                data: geojson
                              },
                              layout: {
                                'line-join': 'round',
                                'line-cap': 'round'
                              },
                              paint: {
                                'line-color': '#ff6500',
                                'line-width': 7,
                                'line-opacity': 0.6
                              }
                            });
                          }
                          // add turn instructions here at the end
                        }
                    
                        map.on('load', () => {
                          // make an initial directions request that
                          // starts and ends at the same location
                          getRoute(start);
                    
                          // Add starting point to the map
                          map.addLayer({
                            id: 'point',
                            type: 'circle',
                            source: {
                              type: 'geojson',
                              data: {
                                type: 'FeatureCollection',
                                features: [
                                  {
                                    type: 'Feature',
                                    properties: {},
                                    geometry: {
                                      type: 'Point',
                                      coordinates: start
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            paint: {
                              'circle-radius': 1,
                              'circle-color': '#3887be'
                            }
                          });
                          // this is where the code from the next step will go
                        });
                        
                    <!-- End draw route -->
```

```
map.on('load', () => {
                            // Add an image to use as a custom marker
                            map.loadImage(
                            'img/blue-marker.png',
                            (error, image) => {
                            if (error) throw error;
                            map.addImage('blue', image);
                            
                            // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                            map.addSource('points', {
                            'type': 'geojson',
                            'data': {
                            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                            'features': [
                            {
                            // feature for Mapbox DC
                            'type': 'Feature',
                            'geometry': {
                            'type': 'Point',
                            'coordinates': [4.897778886724403,52.37883849502549]
                            },
                            'properties': {
                            'title': '1',
                            'description': 'bla'
                            }
                            },
                            
                            }
                            
                            ]
                            }
                            });
                             
                            // Add a symbol layer
                            map.addLayer({
                            'id': 'points',
                            'type': 'symbol',
                            'source': 'points',
                            'layout': {
                            'icon-image': 'blue',
                            'icon-size': 1,
                            // get the title name from the source's "title" property
                            'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
                            'text-font': [
                            'Open Sans Semibold',
                            'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
                            ],
                            'text-offset': [-0.03, -2.2],
                            'text-anchor': 'top',
                            'icon-allow-overlap': true,
                            'text-allow-overlap': true
                            }
                            });
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your second layer on top with

`map.moveLayer(layer_id);` ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently that was the solution. You helped me a lot :)

Comment: No problem, I posted a more detailed solution if needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox allows you to move a layer to a different z-position with `moveLayer();`

If you want to move a layer on the top of everything, use :

```
map.moveLayer('layer_id');
```

Otherwise, you can arrange layers ascending :

```
map.moveLayer('layer_id_beneath', 'layer_id_on_top');
```